# How do I nest schemas using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

```
const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    detail: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    responses: [CommentSchema]

})



const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments: [CommentSchema]


})
```

I keep getting reference error that CommentSchema doesn't exist. How do I nest schemas with mongoose? I think the error is because commentSchema is called inside const commentschema. I've seen this done before so I don't know if its possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the 'response' field after the Schema has been created?

```
const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    detail: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});
CommentSchema.add({ responses: [CommentSchema] });
```

The way I would probably do it though, is keep your original setup and save the responses as ObjectIds of the Comment Model.

```
const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    detail: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    responses: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
});

const Comment = model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

Then just just populate the 'responses' field as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your top snippet, you have `responses: [CommentSchema]` but CommentSchema is undefined still since this snippet IS defining it. You cannot make this kind of recursive definition.